# Proving the following: $\left\lceil(n+1)\log_2{(n+1)}\right\rceil-\left\lceil{n}\log_2{n}\right\rceil = \log_2{n}+2$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, logarithms

I am trying to see if the following statement is true or false:

$$\begin{align}
\left\lceil(n+1)\log_2{(n+1)}\right\rceil - \left\lceil{n}\log_2{n}\right\rceil &= \log_2{n}+2
\end{align}$$
Where *n* ≥ 4 and is a power of two:
$$\begin{align}
n=2^k
\end{align}$$

I have done the following:
$$\begin{align}
\log_2{n} =\log_2{2^k}=k
\end{align}$$
Therefore...
$$\begin{align}
\left\lceil(n+1)\log_2{(n+1)}\right\rceil - {nk} &= k + 2
\end{align}$$
$$\begin{align}
\left\lceil(n+1)\log_2{(n+1)}\right\rceil &= k(n+1) + 2
\end{align}$$

I could do the following to eliminate the remaining ceiling function, but this does not help me:
$$\begin{align}
(n+1)\log_2{(n+1)} + \theta &= k(n+1) + 2
\end{align}$$
$$\begin{align}
where\ \theta \in [0,1)\ is\ some\ unknown\ quantity
\end{align}$$

I am stuck on what to do next with disproving and proving this statement. Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: @Goldname when `n = 4`, for example, the initial equation is true. Therefore, shouldn't your reduced equation be valid for `n = 4`? Reducing shouldn't destroy the meaning of the original equation?

Comment: @Goldname How did you get rid of logs? The ceiling function that contains `n + 1` prevents it.

Comment: my mistake, I missaw it as brackets